# Is Sturm's theorem able to do these?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

$\newcommand{\Ord}{\operatorname{Ord}}$Let $p$ be a positive integer and $F(q)=\sum A(m)q^m$ be a formal power series with integer coefficients. Then $\Ord_p(F(q))$ is defined by
$$\Ord_p(F(q)):=\min\{m\,\vert\, A(m)\not\equiv 0 \pmod p\}.$$
**Sturm's theorem** says that if $f(z)=\sum a(n)q^n$ and $g(z)=\sum b(n)q^n$ are holomorphic modular forms (having integer coefficients) of weight $\pmb{k}$ with respect to some congruence subgroup $\Gamma\subset SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, then $a(n) \equiv b(n)\pmod p$, for a prime $p$, if and only if
$$\Ord_p(f(z)-g(z))>\frac{\pmb{k}}{12}[SL_2(\mathbb{Z}):\Gamma].$$

I can prove that the functions
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq0}M_a(n)\,q^n:=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}(1+q^k)\,q^{\binom{k}2+ak}}{(1-q^k)^{2a}}
\end{align*}
belong to the ring of quasi-modular forms.

If $F(q):=\sum_{n\geq1}\sigma_1(n)q^n$ and $\sigma_s(n)=\sum_{d\,\vert\,n}d^s$ denote the *power-sum of divisors* function, then I can also prove
\begin{align*}
10\sum_{n\geq0}M_2(n)\,q^n&=[7F(q)-1]F(q)+q\frac{d}{dq}F(q), \\
21\sum_{n\geq0}M_3(n)\,q^n&=[19F(q)-3]\sum_{n\geq0}M_2(n)\,q^n-4F(q)^3+F(q)^2+q\frac{d}{dq}\sum_{n\geq0}M_2(n)\,q^n.
\end{align*}
Note that $F(q)$, hence each $\sum M_a(n)\,q^n$, is expressible as a combination of the quasi-modular form $E_2(q)=1-24F(q)$, that is, $F(q)=\frac{1-E_2(q)}{24}$.

The below identity (or expansion) is found experimentally
$$1920\sum_{n\geq 0} M_3(n)\,q^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left[(40n^2+60n+9)\sigma_1(n)
-70(n+1)\sigma_3(n)+31\sigma_5(n)\right]q^n. \label{1}\tag{1}$$

> **QUESTION 1.** Can one apply Sturm's theorem to prove \eqref{1}?

> **QUESTION 2.** Can one apply Sturm's theorem to prove a congruence such as $M_3(8n+4)\equiv 0 \pmod 7$?

Comment: For Q1, since the modular derivative of $E_k$, $k \geq 2$, is known, you can probably express both sides (uniquely) as a finite sum $\sum f_i E_2^i$ with $f_i$ a modular form, that is $f_i \in \mathbb{Q}[E_4, E_6]$, and then apply Sturm's theorem to each $f_i$.

Comment: Thank you, indeed! I was able to settle both questions without Sturm's theorem but but computing the two sides as elements of the ring generated by $E_2, E_4, E_6$. One thing that bothers me is it involves long calculations. Is there an efficient or clever way around it?